# VSCodeでC言語の記述時もJavaと同じようにインデントされるようにしたい

Tags: java, c, vscode

インデントを揃えるときにいつもは cmd+k, cmd+f を使用しており、Javaを記述しているときはインデントが

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    }
```

となるのですが、C言語の記述時に同じショートカットを使用すると

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       ~~~~~~
    }
```

のようになってしまいます。

このインデントが自分としてはとても見にくいのでJavaを記述しているときと同じようにしたいのですが、どのように設定したらいいかわからなかったので聞きたいです。

Comment: この記事 [VSCodeでの中括弧の改行などの整形を変更したい](https://teratail.com/questions/177707) と、その参照先 [clang-format 9 の設定パラメータ まとめ](https://www.pynote.info/entry/clang-format-settings#AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine-bool), [Visual Studio Codeの設定(C/C++編)](https://qiita.com/lunatea/items/0ff9cb103bc45a0f66b7) あたりでしょうか。

Comment: @RugbyRugby フォーマット用にどのような設定を使われていますか？　特に拡張機能を何か導入されていれば、それを「編集」から追記して頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: @kunifさん、@nekketsuuuさん。C_Cpp.clang_format_styleでgoogleを指定してeditor.formatOnSave、editor.formatOnTypeをtrueにしたところ問題が解決しました。回答ありがとうございました！！

Comment: 良かったです、お疲れ様でした！　スタック・オーバーフローでは自分で自分の質問に回答することも[推奨している](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ので、ぜひ回答として投稿いただけませんでしょうか？　少し時間が経てば自分の回答を承認することもできるようになります。是非ご検討ください。

Answer (score 1):

下記の設定で問題が解決しました。

- `C_Cpp.clang_format_style`で`google`を指定
- `editor.formatOnSave`、`editor.formatOnType`を`true`

参考記事:
[VSCodeでの中括弧の改行などの整形を変更したい](https://teratail.com/questions/177707)
[Visual Studio Codeの設定(C/C++編)](https://qiita.com/lunatea/items/0ff9cb103bc45a0f66b7)

---

<sup>この投稿は @Rugby Rugby さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59941/#comment64724_59941)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>